# AdMob ad not showing

Tags: swift, firebase, admob

I implemented AdMob into my app and linked it with Firebase which I am also using for database.

Before that I tried AdMob on new, sample project to see how it works. Its pretty simple so I put it in my app project.

AppDelegate

```
GADMobileAds.configure(withApplicationID: "myAppID")
```

Problem is that I made everything as necessary but my ad is not showing up as it did in sample project. I ran app on my device and added bannerView and configuration for it

```
let request = GADRequest()
request.testDevices = [kGADSimulatorID, "myDeviceID"]

bannerView.adUnitID = "myID"
bannerView.rootViewController = self
bannerView.load(request)
```

**Problem here it because if I enter Firebase testing purpose adUnitID  to test it, it works but with mine it doesn't.**

Any ideas?

Comment: Make sure you enter the right ID exactly, including the right case. Also, make sure that you enter the right one if it's the `~` or `/` in the ID.

Comment: I copied them both in the right place so it should be exactly the same.

Comment: What does it do? Does the Ad not show up, or is it replaced with something else?

Comment: The ad doesnt show. Whote space.

Comment: The problem is admob unique IDs for ads can take up to 24 hours to process and show up. Your doing everything right. If the ad doesn't show up after that It is most likely the views frame thats the problem.